# Google Maps V3: Disable Canvas Markers

Tags: google-maps, canvas, google-maps-markers

On 3/2/11 Google released version 3.4 of Google Maps. The new version uses canvas to create the markers in browsers that support it. I would like to disable this feature. Is that possible?

Comment: The quick fix is to set the version to 3.3 but if anyone knows of a better way, please feel free to let me know! ;)

Answer (score 11):

Check out the `optimized` property of `google.maps.MarkerOptions`.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions

```js
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  icon: getIcon(),
  zIndex: 210,
  map: map,
  optimized: false,
  title: name 
})
```

Comment: This was the only solution to the marker rendering order issue for me; zIndex/setZIndex(..) seems to have no effect on custom markers!